# How can I keep a long-running Drush script from gradually exhausting available RAM?

Tags: drush

I've got a drush script that's used to clear out old, unpublished nodes that have come in from feedapi. The script is fairly simple: get all the nodes with status 0 of a certain type ("post") and age (older than 90 days), loop through them, delete each one.

The script runs through about 4,000 nodes at a time, then exhausts the memory available to its PHP process. I can watch the script's footprint grow from `top` and the 4,000 node limit is somewhat consistent. I've got over 100,000 nodes to work through, though, so I don't think it will be practical to just jack up the RAM available to the process long enough to get a run out of it.

Is there anything I can add at the bottom of each iteration to release the RAM it's consuming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other Options: http://groups.drupal.org/node/189694

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Drupal batch API](http://drupal.org/node/180528) and [call it from Drush](http://drupal.org/node/873132).  You could use the [Drush batchTest unit test](http://drupalcode.org/project/drush.git/blob/HEAD:/tests/batchTest.php) as another reference on how to use the batch API from Drush.

Answer (score 0):

How about getting only a fraction of the nodes at a time from the DB, say 3000 at a time, using SQL's LIMIT (and OFFSET) commands in your SELECT query? Then simply loop over those "chunks".